# Is there a canonical probability measure on smooth curves?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

For continuous curves, we have Brownian motion giving the most natural probability measure. However, the sample paths of Brownian motion are almost surely terribly behaved (not of bounded variation, etc.) Is there an analogue of Brownian motion that yields *smooth* curves? If so, why don't we see it more in the literature?

Comment: Maybe you could consider the curve whose derivative is a brownian motion? These would be $C^1$.

Comment: Given any measurable map $f:C\to C^\infty$ you'll get a pushforward measures $f_\# \gamma$ on $C^\infty$, where $\gamma$ is e.g. a distribution of a Brownian motion. Note that the latter is not a "canonical" measure, it just has certain nice features - e.g. it is a martingale. However, any $C^\infty$ martingale is a constant, so this feature cannot be preserved under a surjective map $f$.